# Slack interactive Button configaration and workflow using botkit,expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, slack, botkit

i want to know about how an interactive button in slack works with the help of botkit,any one show one simple example with the above combination and that will more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this example in the docs?
https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/examples/slack/slackbutton_bot_interactivemsg.js

Comment: Is Interactive buttons and message only works in slack enterprise edition?

Comment: controller.on('interactive_message_callback', function(bot, message) {} at which time they hit this function?